# Add string array to a JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I tried

```
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj["item1"] =  new string[] {"a","b"};
```

and got

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'
```

How do I add a string array to a `JObject`? Also, why do I get that error?

Answer (score 8):

Try this way:

```
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj.Add("item1", JToken.FromObject(new[] { "a", "b" }));
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I tried obj.Add("item1", **JArray**.FromObject(new[] { "a", "b" })); too and it worked. What is the difference?

Comment: @Johnwebner Basically, a `JToken` can be an object or an array, a `JArray` can only be an array

Comment: Looks like `obj.Add("item1", JToken.FromObject(new[] { "a", "b" }));` converts the JToken into a JArray. `obj["item1"].GetType();` results in **{Name = "JArray" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray"}**